# Existence of a limit associated to an almost subadditive sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to prove that a sequence lives in a specific interval; I did prove that lives in a bigger interval, but not in the one I want.

> Let $ a_n $ a sequence such that for any n,m
>   $$a_n + a_m -1 < a_{n+m} < a_n + a_m +1  $$
>   Prove that the sequence  $ (a_n) / n $ converges ( to $L$)  and then prove that 
>   $$ a_n
>  \in \left(nL - 1,nL+1 \right)
> $$

I proved everything, but I proved that lies in $$
\left( nL - 2,nL+2 \right)
$$
I can´t bound it more.

Comment: Put $b_n = a_{n} + 1$ then $b_{n+m} \leq b_{n} + b_{m}$ and thus $$L = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_{n} + 1}{n} = \inf_{n} \frac{a_{n} + 1}{n}. \qquad \text{Moreover, } \frac{a_{n} + 1}{n} \geq L.$$ Similarly with $c_n = 1-a_n$ with $\dfrac{c_n}{n}$ converging to $-L$ and thus $$\frac{1-a_n}{n} \geq -L.$$ This is a classic from [Pólya-Szegő](http://books.google.com/books?id=b9l2NqGEFzg), Exer. 98/99, by the way. (they attribute it to Fekete).

Comment: thanks man, but i did not understood why L equals the inf of this set , and also , can you give me the name of the book please?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I messed up the link. This one should work: it's Pólya-Szegő, *[Problems and theorems in analysis, Volume I: Series, integral calculus, theory of functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=b9l2NqGEFzgC&pg=PA198)*. It's part of the detailed statement that for a subbadditive sequence $d_{n + m} \leq d_{n} + d_{m}$ either there is a lower bound of $d_n/n$ and then $L \leq \frac{d_n}{n}$ and thus the limit equals the infimum or $\frac{d_n}{n}$ diverges properly to $-\infty$. The second case can't happen here because $c_n / n $ has $-L$ as lower bound.

Comment: @Theo: Wikipedia has a reference (found on [Subadditivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity)) to the paper of Fekete: Fekete, M. "Uber die Verteilung der Wurzeln bei gewissen algebraischen Gleichungen mit. ganzzahligen Koeffizienten." Mathematische Zeitschrift 17 (1923), pp. 228–249.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks (man, wanna challenge me with references?! :p) I know that paper, but after looking through it several times I found myself unable to find a compelling reason why exactly it is mentioned by PS... :)

Comment: Sorry for my stupid questions, but I don´t understand only one thing, I know that $ a_n / n $ must converges, obviously your $ b_n / n $ also , but why that limit L must be lower than the inf of that sequence <.<? sorry for ask

Comment: If you cancel the fraction $\dfrac{l_k}{nl_k+r_k}$ with $l_k$ and then let $k \to \infty$ you get $L$ on the left hand side and $\frac{a_n}{n}$ on the right hand side. Note that $a_{r_k} \in \{ a_{0}, \ldots,a_{n-1}\} \leq C$ and $0 \leq r_k/l_k$, so the right hand side can be estimated by $\frac{1}{n} a_{n} + \frac{C}{m_k}$. Now let $k \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my stupid questions, I got it everything

Comment: @Daniel: Please don't use subjective titles like "It's difficult", "it's hard", etc.

Comment: Daniel, come on! No need to feel bad, it's not trivial at all! (I assure you that I spent hours pondering this exercise when I first saw it). I've seen quite a few serious research papers (some from the past 10 years) still giving references for that fact (this rarely happens when people are talking about sequences or series).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two parts to the story here. Detailed arguments and variants can be found in Pólya-Szegő, *[Problems and theorems in analysis, Volume I: Series, integral calculus, theory of functions](http://books.google.com/books?id=b9l2NqGEFzgC&pg=PA198)*, page 198 and 199 (Exercises 98 and 99 of part I)

> Suppose that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers is subadditive: $x_{m+n} \leq x_m + x_n$. Consider $L =  \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_n}{n}$. Either $L = - \infty$ and $\dfrac{a_n}{n}$ diverges properly to $-\infty$, or  $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n} =  \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_n}{n} = L,$$ and in particular the limit exists.

Let $L = \inf\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x_n}{n}$. The case $L = - \infty$ is easy, so assume $L \gt -\infty$. For $\varepsilon \gt 0$ there is an $m$ such that $\frac{x_m}{m} \lt L + \varepsilon$. Writing $n = km + r$ with $0 \leq r \lt m$ we get
$$L \leq \frac{x_{n}}{n} \leq \frac{k \cdot x_m + x_r}{km+r} \leq \frac{x_m}{m}+ \frac{x_r}{n} \leq \frac{x_m}{m} + \frac{C}{n}$$
with $C = \max{\{x_0,\ldots,x_{m-1}\}}.$ For $n \geq C/\varepsilon$ we thus have $\displaystyle L \leq \frac{x_n}{n} \leq \frac{x_m}{m} + \varepsilon \leq L+2\varepsilon$ and thus the limit exists and equals the infimum of the sequence.

---

The second part is:

> Suppose the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ satisfies $-1 + a_m + a_n \leq a_{m+n} \leq 1 + a_m + a_n$. Then the limit $L = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_{n}}{n}$ exists and $L-1 \leq \frac{a_{n}}{n} \leq L+1$.

Note that the sequence $b_n = 1+a_n$ is subadditive: $b_{m+n} \leq b_m + b_n$ hence we can apply the first part to it and find that 
$$-\infty \leq L =  \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1+a_{n}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1+a_{n}}{n} \lt \infty.$$
Similarly, $c_n = 1-a_n$ is subadditive and hence
$$- \infty \leq -L = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1-a_n}{n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-a_n}{n} \lt \infty.$$
Therefore $L$ is a real number and $L \leq \dfrac{1+a_n}{n}$ together with $-L \leq \dfrac{1-a_n}{n}$ yields the desired estimates $nL - 1 \leq a_n \leq nL+1$ where $L = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ also follollows from the above.

---

These lemmas have many applications. An easy variant of this is that a *submultiplicative* sequence of non-negative numbers, that is $a_{n+m} \leq a_n a_m$ has the property that $a_{n}^{1/n}$ converges. This can be used for the [spectral radius formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius#Theorem_.28Gelfand.27s_formula.2C_1941.29) in functional analysis.

Recently, quasi-subadditive sequences have received quite a bit of attention in guise of [quasi-morphisms](http://www.ams.org/notices/200402/what-is.pdf) with significant applications in group theory, dynamical systems, symplectic geometry, and so on.

A beautiful elementary application is [Norbert A'Campo's model of real numbers](http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/acampo-real.pdf) via almost additive maps $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (he calls them slopes), that is functions $\varphi$ satisfying $$\sup\limits_{m,n \in \mathbb{Z}}{|\varphi(m+n) - \varphi(m) - \varphi(n)|} \lt \infty$$ modulo a simple equivalence relation.
The basic idea here is that any real number $r$ yields such a map by setting $\phi(n) = \lfloor rn \rfloor$. The paper is highly recommended, as it contains quite a few ingenious constructions and interesting historical remarks.