# Show that the limit of $\frac{x_n}{n}$ exists

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that $\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$0\leqslant x_{m+n}\leqslant x_m+x_n$$

Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}$ exists.

From the relation, we can show that

$$0\leq x_n\leq x_{n-1}+x_1\leq x_{n-2}+2x_1\leq\dots\leq nx_1$$

Hence

$$0\leq\frac{x_n}{n}\leq x_1$$ 
for all $n$. This means this sequence is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence $\left\{\frac{x_{n_k}}{n_k}\right\}$ with

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{x_{n_k}}{n_k}=c$$

for some $c$. I want to show that the $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n}{n}=c$, and I was stuck.

Comment: See the 1st part of t.b.'s answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57455/existence-of-a-limit-associated-to-an-almost-subadditive-sequence/57493#57493).