# If $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, why $\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$ always exists?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

> If $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, why $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|A^n\|^{1/n}$ always exists?

Thank you.

Comment: This is Gelfand's formula, i.e. that the limit above is equal to the spectral radius $r(A)$. The proof is essentially to show that $\limsup \|A^n\|^{1/n} \leq r(A) \leq \liminf \|A^n\|^{1/n}$. It extends to all elements of a Banach algebra.

Comment: Thank you, I know that this limit is the spectral radius of $A$ but I want to know why this limit is always existing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of the norm inequality $\|AB\|\le\|A\|\|B\|$, the function $f(n)=\log\|A^n\|$ is subadditive ([Subadditivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subadditivity)): $$f(m+n)=\log\|A^{m+n}\|=\log\|A^m\cdot A^n\|\le\log\|A^m\|+\log\|A^n\|=f(m)+f(n),$$ thus by Fekete's lemma, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}n$ exists and is equal to $\displaystyle\inf_{n\ge1}\frac{f(n)}n$.

Comment: I will ad this link as a useful resource for Fekete's lemma and some related topics: [Existence of a limit associated to an almost subadditive sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57455#57493).

Comment: @Martin Sleziak That resource may be very useful, indeed. Fekete's lemma and a distant cousin (Jensen's inequality) share the fate to be extremely helpful in some situations, but much less well-known than they deserve.